# Rails refer to a field name and not the relationship between 2 tables when the name is the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I have a model named Director which references a table with a field named also 'director'.

When I do queries that use joins (either with the relationship in the model or using the .joins method) then try to print the director field, I get the relationship instead of the field, so when doing

```
<% @dvds.each do |dvd| %>
<%= "#{dvd.director}" %>
```

I get something like:

```
#<Director id: 93, director: "Brad Bird">
```

When I should get just "Brad Bird".

Is there a way to disambiguate this and get only the field name without having to change my Model names?

Comment: Can you describe your DVD and Director models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things:

Use the field like:

```
<%= "#{dvd.director.director}" %>
```

Or add a to_s to the model like:

```
class Director

  def to_s
    self.director
  end

end
```

By the way, it's a bit weird to have a `director` field on a `Director` model

Comment: I tried this `<%= "#{dvd.director.director}" %>` and I got an undefined method error for director. Presumably the second one.

Comment: @kakubei Are you sure that each dvd has a director? Maybe that is the problem... As far as I can understand from your details what I've posted should just work fine.

Comment: You would recommend I change the model name?

Comment: Maybe the field name. "dvd.director.name" is more readable than "dvd.director.director". Obviously it is a matter of taste

Comment: I can't change anything in the database design because it's already used by a PHP app.

Comment: not all of them have a director, no, but the resulting sql actually calls an INNER JOIN so it would return only rows that do have a director associated. I understand that the only way around that is to use .joins and explicitly write out the LEFT JOIN (for that I might as well just use find_by_sql) or use .includes, but the latter doesn't seem do JOINS but rather separate queries.

Comment: I think the problem might have been that I was doing a GROUP_CONCAT() on director and that requires an alias if you want to use a sane field name. Your solution worked for studio.studio though. Thanks.